# HTML Mail Outlook - fix table width so that it is not broken when viewed on different screens

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have a python script that generates an HTML email body and send it out to users. 
the Email has a table of data being generated and the table is best viewed at 600px.
I have some users who mainly watch the emails on mobile and becuase of which the table shrinks and the format breaks. 
Is there a way to keep the table width fixed to 600 and the user viewing on mobile has to scroll it to the right to view the full content, without shrinking the / sizes.

Comment: Fixed-width images have broken my emails like this before, so they might be the solution for you :)

Comment: @Frish- problem for one may be the solution to the other :) I will try this. BTW, only wrapping the content in img tag and giving it a width would work ? or I need to do something else ?

Comment: you can't wrap things in an image tag, but try `<img width="600" style="width:600px !important;" src="spacer.gif">` in the `td` containing the `table`

Comment: Oh yes sorry forgot that we can't wrap in img tag. But the below from bryan helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how well this will work for you.  But it's where I would start.

```html
<body style="overflow-x: scroll;"> 
  <table style="width: 600px;" width="600">
    <tr>
      <td nowrap>Things and stuff that is over 600px</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd also add `width="600"` on the table as certain email clients don't play nice with styles. Ugh, emails...

Comment: Good call @Frish! I added that. Ugh... emails... /nod

Comment: Yes. Adding width="" worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Saved me a lot of hours. Otherwise would have to change the table format.